# Spring 3, Using TransactionalTemplate in a service call test?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, transactions

I can't get quite a simple test scenario to work. Logically (to me) it should, but it don't

I have a transactional service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void addCustomer(Customer newCustomer)  {
    customerDAO.insert(newCustomer);
}
```

So it's set to start a transaction or reuse an existing one. I have `tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"` set in the app context, so Spring sees this service as transactional.

I have a test that calls this code, that works fine.

But I wanted another test to verify a rollback. So I created a test which calls a TranscationTemplate block, eg:

```
   final int preCount = service.getCustomerCount();;

    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {

                // adding another and rolling back
                Customer c = new Customer();
                                    .
                                    .
                  service.addCustomer(c);

                status.setRollbackOnly();
                throw new RuntimeException("rollback");
```

I assumed this would rollback the addCustomer service call, as both this block and the service should (?) be sharing the same transaction.

But the rollback never happens

Anyone any ideas why? Can you not share programatic and declarative transactions?

**Edit**>
Target DB is H2.

Junit defined as follows:

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/customer-application-context.xml"})

public class TestAddCustomer extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
```

The transactionManager is autowired in the class.

Comment: Should have worked! just for clarification, you got the reference to the transactionManager, service via a Spring Junit support based test right? and also can you clarify which DB you are using - an embedded h2 or hsql?

Comment: I thought it should have worked too! I've edited my entry for some extra stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: can you check you have same transaction status object addCustomer and doInTransaction. to get transaction status object in addCustomer you can use  TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(), i feel that because of some reason it has different transaction status

Comment: Try to add println methods for assurance that it met rollback statement.